# Creating chart from multi level Object in D3

Tags: d3.js

Folks-
I receive the data in the following format and I am trying to put a multi-line chart in D3.
I need to use the key as my x axis and value as y; and draw 1 line of each of the year. I am not able to get the xScale and yScale values. Is there a way to get this done?

````
{"year":"2017","values":
    [{"key":"3","value":1},{"key":"4","value":19},{"key":"5","value":176},{"key":"6","value":524},{"key":"7","value":284},{"key":"8","value":31}]},
{"year":"2018","values":
    [{"key":"3","value":4},{"key":"4","value":15},{"key":"5","value":152},{"key":"6","value":532},{"key":"7","value":367},{"key":"8","value":55}]},
{"year":"2019","values":
    [{"key":"3","value":1},{"key":"4","value":10},{"key":"5","value":88},{"key":"6","value":497},{"key":"7","value":410},{"key":"8","value":72},{"key":"9","value":3}]},
{"year":"2020","values":
    [{"key":"1","value":1},{"key":"2","value":1},{"key":"3","value":1},{"key":"7","value":398},{"key":"8","value":107},{"key":"9","value":4}]},
{"year":"2021","values":
    [{"key":"6","value":28},{"key":"7","value":78},{"key":"8","value":52},{"key":"9","value":8}]}
]```

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we have to loop through the given data and find the xDomain and yDomain.

```
 // find the domain and the range, assuming the starting value for xscale and yscale 
is 0. Adjust accordingly
const xDomain = [0, 0];
const yDomain = [0, 0];

data.forEach((yearData) => {
yearData.values.forEach((valObj) => {
  const key = valObj.key;
  const value = valObj.value;

  xDomain[1] = Math.max(xDomain[1], parseInt(key)); // find max x value
  yDomain[1] = Math.max(yDomain[1], value); // find max y value

  // here, you can also set the min values similarly
  // xDomain[0] = Math.min(xDomain[0], parseInt(key));
  // yDomain[0] = Math.min(yDomain[0], value);
});
});
```

Working example : [D3 V5 Multi Line Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/UmeshMaharshi30/be5d52fa18f915469fe001b7e02ff2df)